# add.s $f8,$f10,$f12 in MIPS to binary

Tags: assembly, mips, machine-code

I'm trying to write

```
add.s $f8,$f10,$f12
```

(MIPS) in binary. I got

```
01011 01010 01100 01010 01000 000000
```

MARS compiles this as

```
010001  10000   01100   01010   01000   000000
```

Not sure what went wrong. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you're only showing 31 digits.

Second, you have put into the opcode and fmt fields decimal numbers 11 and 10, but they are hex 11 and 10 (decimal 17 and 16).

At the top of the [MIPS Green Sheet](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/MIPS_Green_Sheet.pdf), first page, the header for the very last column says: (Hex).  We can also verify this by seeing some of the values in that column, e.g. the `FUNCT` code shows `1a` for `div` and the `OPCODE` field shows `3d` for `sdc1`.

On another note, the Green Sheet is super confusing, so you have to read it with care.  Take the "OPCODES, BASE CONVERSION, ASCII SYMBOLS" table, for example, which does binary <-> decimal <-> hex for 6 binary digits, while showing opcode and funct fields along with the ASCII chart — an extraordinary table.

Comment: Right, I forgot this stuff was in hex. Thanks.